# How are Japanese company division, section or department names translated?

Tags: translation, business-japanese

How are Japanese company division, section or  department names usually translated to English e.g. 「システム開発1部ソリューション１課」? Does it translate it to System Development Department 1 Solution Section 1?

Comment: Correct in my experience

Answer (score 2):

Division, Department and Section are usually translated as 事業本部 / 事業部、部 and 課 respectively. But the names of organizational units differ from company to company. For example, in mass-media (TV and press) and advertising agencies where I had worked, Division, Department and Section were respectly called 局、部、課.
Goverment organizations also use 局、部、課.

金融部 will be Finance Department, but I don't think the use of the word, 'team' as a nomencrature of the organizational unit is so popular. You have a taskforce team, or new business / product / design development team as a sub- unit in a department or section, but we don't see the title of the manager / chief of XX Team of its own instead of　部 and 課　so often.

Comment: I'm a bit confused to find the significant change in the editing of the OP's  text, where the OP asked about the indication of Team i.e. Finance Team in an organizational chart. Please note that my answer corresponds to OP's original form of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the company but I work for a department similar to one you described (minus the numbers) and it is translated quite similarly to what you have said.

Some discrepancies would be things like whether the department is written as a Kanji-base or a Katakana-base.

> 金融部 > Finance Department
> ファイナンス部 > Finance Department

Also note that some companies do not use 課 but instead implement team names or project names / acronyms instead.

> 金融部　MZHチーム > Finance Department MZH Team
>
> サービスソリューション部、　システム開発「さくら」 Service Solutions Department, System Development Team - Sakura